# How do I use methods outside a specific class?

Tags: ruby

I have two classes (I can't combine them), each in their own file.
File number 1:

```
class A
  def say_hi
    puts "Hi"
  end
end
```

File number 2:

```
class B
  def say_bye
    puts "bye"
  end
end
```

I can do:

```
apple = A.new
apple.say_hi
```

Or:

```
 baby = B.new
 apple.say_bye
```

But what if I want to do:

```
apple = A.new
apple.say_bye
```

Or:

```
baby = B.new
baby.say_hi
```

Is there a simple way to do that without restructuring my classes?

Comment: You are challenging OOP ... :-) If one is module and another is class, it is possible..but class - class.. I don't know.

Comment: You mean if I changed say_hi to a module, I can have the 2 classes "require" the module and then run it that way?

Comment: yes.. that's how it works...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BroiSatse Nothing.. testing the temperature of Ruby.. :)

Comment: In my real program, i have a runner file and depending on what the user selects, it runs either a method from class A or a method from class B. Obviously I have to create a new instance of whichever class to start running the program, so as of now, my program only works if the method matches the class of the new instance variable.

Comment: Why are the methods named differently? It'd be easier if you had an interface, then you could use duck typing. Or just add aliases.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a case of "which class I should instantiate?" and all you know is you want method "say_hi" then you could do...

```
method = :say_hi

if A.new.respond_to?(method) 
  runner_object = A.new
else
  runner_object = B.new
end
```

active support in Rails lets you do...

```
result = A.new.try(:say_hi) || B.new.try(:say_hi)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to call these different methods from a flow which gets either one of these classes.

The easiest way to do this is by using [`alias_method`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method):

```
class A
  def say_hi
    puts "Hi"
  end
  alias_method :say, :say_hi
end

class B
  def say_bye
    puts "bye"
  end
  alias_method :say, :say_bye
end

apple = A.new
apple.say
# => "Hi"

baby = B.new
baby.say
# => "bye"
```

You can even do it if you can't actually change the class code, by using [`class_eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-class_eval):

```
A.class_eval { alias_method :say, :say_hi }
B.class_eval { alias_method :say, :say_bye }
```